# Display info on page by list and or title altered by toggle button

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am not sure what to look for or how to look for examples for this so any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

I have a view page that displays a list of users by their name and then little icons for email - picture - profile page.

I want to create a toggle button on the page that will change the display page for the users and display them by the user picture and then little icons for email and profile.

Are there any examples with this feature?

I am using asp.net mvc4 c# VS2012. Thanks

Comment: why do people vote down? If some people think it might be a stupid question then why not provide a simple answer or a sense direction of where to look.

Comment: You should have to leave a comment if you vote down, whats wrong with that?

Comment: The question is a little bit too general for SO. If you had a specific implementation detail that you needed help with, it would be more likely to get an answer. That said, if you're a beginner, then it would probably be easiest to create a second view with the different layout. Otherwise, maybe something that used jQuery to change the default CSS to tweak how elements were displayed.

Comment: @Amina I'm sorry, I couldn't understand your question. Could you provide  more info, like a draw of what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a controller that provides getting people data, then simplest way to reach your goal is to create two different views (one with display list of users by their name and another with display by user picture). Then toggle button may be just the html link to another view.

Comment: Would i be able to use jquery for the toggle?

Comment: Sure! In this case you will need only one view, but you will need to store your people data inside hidden fields in the html markup. May be you want to apply some client-side template engine. **jsRender**, for example.